# SSRS 2008 R2 - Add total line to chart

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have created a line chart that displays the different types of messages sent over a month (Email, Print, Voice) which are displaying on the chart just fine.
Is there an easy way to add another line which totals the values for the 3 series without changing the SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two way to do this in reporting services:

**1. Directly in the chart**

Add a new series to your line chart. Set the expression for the value to be

=Fields!Email.Value + Fields!Print.Value + Fields!Voice.Value

**2. With a calculated field in the dataset**

Set the calculated field "AllMessages" to be the sum of Email, Print and Voice. Then add AllMessages to your chart. [Youtube Walkthrough calculated field](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46nE6tfGsgA)

Comment: I actually was grouping individual messages and the email, print, and voice numbers are all on different rows, not in individual columns.
I have changed the SQL to UNION and GROUP BY so that Total is a separate row that is directly placed on the chart.
I will accept your answer since it would work if I had my data grouped as you surmised and you taught me about calculated fields.
Thanks !!!